# Restrict a program to only access files in a specific folder not containing it

Tags: security

I have a folder `F` and a program `P` *outside* of the folder `F`. How to make `P` only able to access files in `F`? Answers for any OS are accepted but preferably something that work in Debian.

E.g
`F` is `~/playarea` and `P` is `~/prog`. I want `~/prog` to able to read, modify, and execute `~/playarea/foo` but not `~/others` or **itself**.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear, specific and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details about both your environment and what you have already tried. - In that regard *"Answers for any OS are accepted"* is way too broad and makes your question sound hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to run `P` as user `Puser` and then modify permissions of directory `~/playarea` so `P` can access it. You could make `Puser` member of the group of the `~/playarea` directory and if that is not an option you could use ACL in the directory with something like `setfacl -R -m user:git:rwx,default:user:git:rwx ~/playarea`. With that command user `Puser` will have read, write and execute access to all the contents in `~/playarea`

Comment: But wouldn't Puser have access to P then?

Comment: Yes, but it's a standard practice to have a dedicated user for a program/service so you can create `Puser` dedicated for that program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a program that can't read it's own executable can't run at all actually.

Comment: @Pablo Hmm... seems like the best i can achieve is to do what u said and then `chmod 001 P`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, obviously the program must be able to read it or run as root and then drop privileges and convert to user `Puser` (more info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737/dropping-root-privileges)

Comment: @siyu how are you going to launch the program `P`?

Comment: Edit: `chmod 100 P`

Comment: @Pablo do u mean `P` is owned and started by root (`Puser` has no access to `P` the executable at all), and the process drops privilege to `Puser` after starting?